# SQL PIVOT not showing NULL results

Tags: sql, join, dynamic, pivot

I have a transaction table that I want to PIVOT (Quantity by Month).  The below query executes fine but it excludes items that have no values (and don't exist) in the Tx table.  I used the GIP table (a full list of all items and various information about each item) first and joined the Tx table to it, but that did not work.  I also tried LEFT OUTER JOIN and also adding a NULL qualifier into the WHERE clause.
Bonus if anyone can convert this to a Dynamic Query for the Months, in order.

```
SELECT 
   CAST([item_no] AS INT) 'IMF',
   [1] AS 'Jan',
   [2] AS 'Feb',
   [3] AS 'Mar',
   [4] AS 'Apr',
   [5] AS 'May',
   [6] AS 'Jun',
   [7] AS 'Jul',
   [8] AS 'Aug',
   [9] AS 'Sep',
   [10] AS 'Oct',
   [11] AS 'Nov',
   [12] AS 'Dec'
FROM 
   (SELECT
          GIP.[Station__No],
          GIP.[generic_inventory],
          GIP.[item_no],
          (Tx.[Quantity]*-1) Qty,
          MONTH(Tx.[Date_Posted]) TMonth
    FROM
    [Surgery].[genericx_inventory_item_445_01] GIP
    LEFT JOIN [CDWWork].[IFCAP].[inventory_transaction_445_2] Tx ON Tx.[station__no] = GIP.[station__no] AND Tx.[Inventory_Point] = GIP.[generic_inventory] AND GIP.[Itemnox] = Tx.[Item_no]

   where GIP.[Station__no] = 658
   and Tx.[Date_Posted] >= '7/01/16'
   and Tx.[Date_Posted] <= '6/30/17'
   and GIP.[generic_inventory] = 623
   ) As x
PIVOT
( 
   SUM(Qty)
   FOR TMonth
   IN( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
)P
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the pivot  Your `LEFT JOIN` is wrong.  The conditions on the *second* table need to be in the `ON` clause:

```
FROM [Surgery].[genericx_inventory_item_445_01] GIP LEFT JOIN
     [CDWWork].[IFCAP].[inventory_transaction_445_2] Tx
     ON Tx.[station__no] = GIP.[station__no] AND
        Tx.[Inventory_Point] = GIP.[generic_inventory] AND
        GIP.[Itemnox] = Tx.[Item_no] AND
        Tx.[Date_Posted] >= '2016-07-01' AND
        Tx.[Date_Posted] <= '2017-06-30'
WHERE GIP.[Station__no] = 658 AND GIP.[generic_inventory] = 623
```

While you are at it, you should use standard date formats.  Less ambiguous (and easier to read ;).

Comment: Yes, indeed!  Thanks so much!